# efficient search in mongodb v2.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, search

I'm using version 2.4 of mongodb which is working fine for my needs, except one thing, i.e. **searching** as it doesn't support some advanced options like **$search**. So, is there a way to implement that kind of searching in v2.4. The reason i'm sticking to older version is because i don't want to lose any of my data by upgrading and also i don't want to stop live  mongo server.
The result i want should be something similar as this query's result:

```
db.data.find({$text: { $search: 'query' } }, { score: {$meta: "textScore" }})
```

This query is working fine for latest versions of mongoDB. And also if you people suggest me to use the latest version, please provide some references which can help me safely upgrading mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit of a catch 22, introduced mainly by text search capabilities being considered "experimental" in earlier versions. Aside from being in an earlier development phase, the implementation is entirely different due to the fact that the "whole" query and index API has been re-written for MongoDB 2.6, largely in order to support the new types of indexes available and make the API for working with the data consistent.

So prior versions implement text search via the "command" interface directly and only. Things work a little differently and the current "deprecation" notice means that working in this way will be removed. But the [**"text"**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/command/text/) command will presently still operate as shown in the earlier documentation:

```js
db.data.runCommand("text", { "search": "query" })
```

So there are limitations here as covered in the existing documentation. Notably being that the number of documents returned are those contained the "limit" argument to that command and there is no concept of "skip". Also that this is a "document" response and not a cursor, so the total results cannot exceed the BSON limit of 16MB.

That said, a little off topic but consider your MongDB 2.6 deployment scenario, and mostly on the following.

1. **Future Proofing**. In the earlier forms this is an experimental feature. So any general flaws and problems are not going to generally be "backported" in any way with fixes while you hang on to the version. Some may, but without a good reason to do so this mostly wanes over time. Remember this is "experimental" so due warning was given about use in production.
2. **Consistency/Deprecation**. The API for "text" and "geospatial" has changed. So implementation in earlier releases is different and "deprecated", and will go away. The right way is to have the same structure as other queries, and consistently use it in all query forms rather than a direct command.
3. **Deployment**. You say you don't wan't to stop the server, but you really should not have one server anyway. Apart from being out of the general philosophy of why you need MongoDB anyway, at the very least a "replica set" is a good idea for data redundancy and the "uptime" of your application. Removing a single point of failure means that you can individually "bring down" discrete nodes and "upgrade" without affecting application downtime.

So that strays "a little" off the programming topic, but for me, the last point is the most important. Better to make sure your application is without the failure points by building this into your deployment architecture. This then makes "staying ahead of the curve" a simpler decision. It is always worth noting the "experimental" clause with technologies before rolling out to production. Cover your bases.

Comment: @Ravi I actually had a bit more to say about this rather than just pointing out the "command" form. The full details are worth considering before just deciding to code this way.

Comment: That's a nice consideration to consider, and i'll consider this for future developments :)

Comment: I have one one more query, can i match any secondary field in the same query??

Comment: @Ravi As I said, it is different. This is covered by the "filter" condition in the command. See the linked manual page for all of the details.